# Problem with Tkinter - Inheritance problems

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm starting to work with classes with a Tkinter app, but I don't seem to understand how classes work, especially the relationship parent-controller. As you can see in the code down below, I was planning to have an outer class for a whole section, then 4 inner classes for every section within that frame. However, I cannot call those classes from the initial frame. Is there any better way to do this? What is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
class MainScreenFrameCenter(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent, bg="white",height=680, width=640,highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
        self.controller = controller
        self.pack(side="top",  fill="both", expand=True)

        self.widgets_nw = MainScreenFrameCenterNW(parent=self,controller=self)
        self.widgets_sw = MainScreenFrameCenterSW(parent=self,controller=self)
        self.widgets_ne = MainScreenFrameCenterNE(parent=self,controller=self)
        self.widgets_se = MainScreenFrameCenterSE(parent=self,controller=self)

    class MainScreenFrameCenterNW(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args,**kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,height=350,width=640,bg="white",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
            self.controller = controller
            self.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
    class MainScreenFrameCenterSW(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args,**kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,height=350,width=640,bg="white",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
            self.controller = controller
            self.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="nsew")
    class MainScreenFrameCenterNE(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args,**kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,height=350,width=640,bg="white",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
            self.controller = controller
            self.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nsew")
    class MainScreenFrameCenterSE(tk.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent, controller,*args,**kwargs):
            tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent,height=350,width=640,bg="white",highlightbackground="black",highlightthickness=1)
            self.controller = controller
            self.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: _"I cannot call those classes from the initial frame."_ - why not? What do you mean by "call those classes"? What happens when you try?

Comment: Are you intentionally putting those other classes inside `ManScreenFrameCenter`? That's highly unusual.

Comment: For example, it says that MainScreenFrameCenterNW doesn't exist. FrameCenter is basically the bigger frame which is split into 4 sections. I set them within MainScreenFrameCenter as they belong to that frame, should I just put them outside?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move all of the class definitions to global scope by putting them all at the same level of indentation.

```
class MainScreenFrameCenter(tk.Frame):
    ...
class MainScreenFrameCenterNW(tk.Frame):
    ...
class MainScreenFrameCenterSW(tk.Frame):
    ...
class MainScreenFrameCenterNE(tk.Frame):
    ...
class MainScreenFrameCenterSE(tk.Frame):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are attempting to make a small grid. Classes are generally not nested inside of another class. If you create a class that represents 1 grid cell, you can use a loop to create a grid from it.

```
import tkinter as tk


class Cell(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, column:int=0, row:int=0, **kwargs):
        kwargs = {**{'bg':'white', 'highlightbackground':'black','highlightthickness':1}, **kwargs}
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.grid(column=column, row=row, sticky='nswe')
        
        
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.configure(**kwargs)
        
        cols = 2
        for i in range(cols):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
            
        rows = 2
        for i in range(rows):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=1)
        
        for i, c in enumerate(['nw', 'ne', 'sw', 'se']):
            self.__dict__[f'widgets_{c}'] = Cell(self, i%cols, i//cols)
            
            
        self.widgets_nw['background'] = 'red'
                
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = App(background="white", highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1)
    root.geometry('640x680+300+300')
    root.title('not Can is Should Example')
    root.mainloop()
```